# LINQ to XML grouping with sum

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am currently working with this xml (this is a small subset):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <order>
        <customer><![CDATA[1035]]></customer>
        <total><![CDATA[10]]></total>
    </order>
    <order>
        <customer><![CDATA[1036]]></customer>
        <total><![CDATA[5.6]]></total>
    </order>
    <order>
        <customer><![CDATA[1035]]></customer>
        <total><![CDATA[5.6]]></total>
    </order>
</orders>
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to group this by customer and sum the total.

When I iterate through groupings I would have:

```
customer 1035 with a total of 15.6
customer 1036 with a total of 5.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first transform, then group/sum:

```
var query = from element in doc.Descendants("order")
            select new { Customer = (int) element.Element("customer"),
                         Total = (decimal) element.Element("total") }
            into order
            group order.Total by order.Customer into g
            select new { Customer = g.Key, Total = g.Sum() };

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("customer {0} with a total of {1}",
                      result.Customer, result.Total);
}
```

(You could do all of this in dot notation as well, of course.)